# "Disable view selector menu" NOT working

Tags: 2013, web-part, document-library, list-view-web-part

**How can I make "Disable view selector menu" remain unchecked?**

- I inserted a document library to a web part on a page.
- Under Edit Web Part > Miscellaneous, I unchecked "Disable view
  selector menu".
- I clicked "Apply" and the "view selector menu" appears in Edit mode. (Yay!)
- However, when I click "Save" or "Check in" and "view selector menu"
  disappears. (Boo!)
- I return to edit the web part and "Disable view selector menu" is
  checked.

**I am using SharePoint 2013 (Build 15.0.4420.1017).**

I created the following:

- Custom Master Page
- Custom Page Layout (with Web Parts)
- Custom Document Library

Thanks!